# How to get value from entered in ckeditor using ngModel in angular 8?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular8, angular-ngmodel, ckeditor5

```html
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="editorData" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
```

How can i get the value of text inputted from ckeditor using ngmodel from html to component. I am using angular 8 and ckeditor 5

Answer (score 2):

**With `ngModel`**

You'll already have the data in your component with 2-way binding. So the `editorData` property will have the most up-to-date value.

[ckeditor ngModel](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#integration-with-ngmodel)

**With `change` event**

You can use the `(change)` event from the editor.

```html
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" (change)="onChange($event)"></ckeditor>
```

```js
import { ChangeEvent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component';

@Component( {
    // ...
} )
export class MyComponent {
    public onChange( { editor }: ChangeEvent ) {
        const data = editor.getData();

        console.log( data );
    }
    ...
}
```

[ckeditor change](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#change)

Comment: i'm not getting the colors and alignments.. any idea why ?

Comment: edit: never mind this was the problem "HTML stripped some content "